# Issue with SFINAE in Ideone?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to debug an issue I'm getting with Visual Studio by comparing the output of Visual Studio with the output of GCC, but I can't seem to get an extremely simplified version of the code to compile in Ideone:

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

template <int x>
struct foo {};

template <>
struct foo<0> { using type = int; };

template <typename Foo>
struct bar
{
    bar(void) {}

    template <typename = typename Foo::type>
    bar(const bar &) {}
};

int main(void)
{
    bar<foo<1>> x;
}
```

The above gives me the error when I try to run it using Ideone:

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct bar<foo<1> >’:
prog.cpp:21:17:   required from here
prog.cpp:16:5: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct foo<1>’
     bar(const bar &) {}
```

From my understanding, the failure to substitute `Foo::type` should not result in a compilation error. Note that making the copy constructor `bar(const bar &) { typename Foo::type x; }` allows the program to compile just fine. I'm trying to use this template in pretty much the exact same way that `std::enable_if` is used, which also causes compilation errors when used anywhere within the class - not just on the copy constructor. Is this correct behavior? I'm fairly certain it's not, but I've always thought that Ideone uses GCC in the back-end...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this behavior is correct.

SFINAE applies when **deducing template parameters during function template overload resolution** (the compiler is allowed to discard a specialization without emitting an error).

In your case the error did not occur during overload resolution, but during the template instantiation : the `bar` template simply cannot be instantiated, since the copy constructor requires the existence of the nested type `Foo::type`, which doesn't exist when the template parameter is `foo<1>`.

For your last point, if you declare :

```
template <typename Foo>
struct bar
{
    bar(void) {}

    bar(const bar &) { typename Foo::type x; }
};
```

It compiles fine as long as you don't call the copy constructor.
Using the copy constructor will cause the same compilation error :

```
bar<foo<1>> x2 = x; // Error
```

Comment: That's a bit odd and undesirable, but whatever. Anyway, while not directly giving a solution, you helped me get there myself. Answer edited with the change I need

Comment: EDIT: What I added earlier actually doesn't work for this situation, but does for my overall situation.